# UISearchBar issue with UIsearchBarBackground

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have strange issue with UISearchBar when I click on the textBox it gets animated and displayed incorrect. SearchBar is shifted down for 20px. I found that gray background is UISearchBarBackground.

I tried different approaches to remove it, but UISearchBarBackground is not exists in searchBar subviews.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

[image]